# Does there exist a relationship between elasticity tensor $E_{ijkl}$ and $\int_{\Gamma} F^i z^i d \Gamma$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, elasticity, material-science

Does there exist a relationship between elasticity tensor $$E_{ijkl}$$ and $$\int_{\Gamma} F^i z^i d \Gamma$$ where $F^i$ is force and $z^i$ displacement. $\Gamma$ is loaded boundary.

I see these two formulations in shape optimization problem formulations using *material distribution method*. That makes me think that these two are equal, but I cannot see how.

Comment: If neither of the two answers are sufficient maybe you can provide more info in your question?

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things.

The elasticity tensor is a property of an elastic material, and it represents a density of stiffness. It relates stresses ($\sigma_{ij}$) with strains ($\epsilon_{ij}$) (using Einstein summation):

$$\sigma_{ij} = E_{ijkl} \epsilon_{kl}\, .$$

Your second expression represents the work done over your body while subjected to a force $F^{i}$, and moves a distance $z^{i}$.

Also, see that one quantity is a fourth order tensor while the other is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Power stress $\cfrac{dW}{dt}=\sigma_{ij}D_{ij}$, where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the stress tensor and $D_{ij}$ is the velocity gradient, and the velocity gradient is just the strain $ϵ_{ij}$ per time unit. This relation might help you to constrain the problem more.

$$\cfrac{dW}{dt}=\sigma_{ij}D_{ij} = \sigma_{ij}\frac{ϵ_{ij}}{dt}$$

so with W=$\int_\Gamma F^iz^i d\Gamma$

$$\int_\Gamma F^iz^i d\Gamma= \sigma_{ij}{ϵ_{ij}} = (E_{ijij}ϵ_{ij})ϵ_{ij}$$

Which might be simplified further...